# What will be the best way to replace self

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, self

I have this code that works great, but out of curiosity how can I replace the word `self` in this method?This is a navigation app btw, and been trying all sorts of methods to replace it.

Viewcontroller1

```
  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Here is one method I tried,

```
UIViewController *vc;

    vc = [[Viewcontroller1 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [vc.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: What do you mean by replacing the word? What exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: purpose to replace `self`?

Comment: basically seeing if I can substitute it.

Comment: yes.. why do you want it replace? and with what?

Comment: I don't know, maybe an object or something. Just wanting to see. I posted an update so you can see a better understanding.

Comment: why do you want to do such thing self is a keyword

Comment: oh okay.. yes you definitely can do that.. but you should know when to do it and where should it be done. e.g vc = [[Viewcontroller1 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [vc.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; this statement is of no use because you just created the object of the view controller and you trying to popitup from the navigation stack.. but you didnt even created navigationcontroller/stack for that and you haven't pushed it in the stack

Comment: Basically wanting to substitute self with a block of code.

Comment: Technically you could do `ViewController1 *vc = self;` and than you could use vc instead of self, although I don't know why you would want to do that.

Comment: @Kunal cool can you show me an example, it can be any example not pertaining to my code, just like to know for future reference.

Comment: I am sure you must be knowing that, poping out the controller is only posible when your controller is in the navigationstack. And navigationstack is acheived using navigation controller, I mean navigation controller creates a navigation stack to maintain all the controllers. Now lets say you have two navigation controllers in the application each has 5 view controllers in its stack(just for example). Now if as per the user's action you want to pop view controller from one of the navigation controller, you can use popViewControllerAnimated method on one of viewcontrollers from the navstack.

Comment: @Jsdodgers, is it possible to write that code in view controller 2 with modifications of course?

Comment: if you use that in view controller 2, you would get a reference to the `self` of view controller 2, not viewController1

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to replace `self`. Because `self` is a `keyword` like `this` `keyword` in JAVA.

**IN SHORT** Apple/iOS Does not provede any types of Feature That any people can change it.

---

```
                                      **EDIT**
```

---

**From Your Code :**

```
UIViewController *vc;

    vc = [[Viewcontroller1 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [vc.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

The best way for create object of `Viewcontroller1` and navigate to another **viewController** for write as

```
Viewcontroller1 *objVC = [[Viewcontroller1 alloc] init]; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController: objVC animated:YES];
```

Comment: So, there is no substitute? Because if I executed my second block of code nothing happens. But my first block of code works great.

Comment: @FelixJones-check my edited :)

Answer (score 0):

You are wrongly interpreting below line of code.

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This line basicaly what does . it does remove from the viewController form current NavigationViewControlelr's (i.e self.navitionController )Stack

stack-- basically when you create any `viewController` and that `view Controller` into the `navigationController`, then `navigation controller` add that `viewController` according to the `Stack` or can say manage the `ViewController in stack's Way`.

And About the your below line of code

```
 UIViewController *vc;

 vc = [[Viewcontroller1 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
 [vc.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Why u are creating ViewController removing form the navigationViewController. it'll craete memory overhead

and About replacing the `self`. you can't replace  `self` as  `iPatel' told above.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you want to replace `self` with "an object or something", `self` *is* an object.  The word self refers to the current instance of the class that the function is in.  You cannot replace `self` because then you would not be referencing the current instance of your UIViewController subclass.

Why your example does not work:

```
UIViewController *vc;

    vc = [[Viewcontroller1 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [vc.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Is because it is referencing a new instance of the `Viewcontroller1` class.  The popover will not appear because you are not adding it to your current viewcontroller; you are adding it to another instance that is never displayed.